# How can a nonconvex polytope be defined (not by an LMI)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, inequality, polytopes

A convex polytope can be defined by an LMI (linear matrix inequality) or a list of points. How can a nonconvex polytope be defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (general) polytope is a finite union of convex polytopes.

Comment: See [here](http://www.math.washington.edu/~grunbaum/Your%20polyhedra-my%20polyhedra.pdf)